# How can i declare a function as async in a Interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Interface and a Class which implements the methods, I didn't find a answer to my Problem by now. I have a function defined `myAsyncFunction()` in the Interface and i want to make it **async**:

```
export interface State {
  state: Class;

  myAsyncFunction(): any;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the caller, an async function is just a function that returns a promise:

```
export interface State {
  state: string;
  myAsyncFunction(): Promise<any>;
}

const state : State = {
  state: 'foo',
  myAsyncFunction: async () => 'bar'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't care if a function uses the `async` keyword. It only cares that it *is* a function, what arguments it takes, and what the return value is.

The only significance of the `async` keyword in that context is that the function will return a promise … which will be matched by `any`.

Comment: While this _works_, it does have the disadvantage that you can return something other than a promise, and you can't be more specific about what you _really_ return. So if you type it to return `string` instead, it won't work.

Comment: @gustafc — That's general advice about `any` and not specific to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Function is async when returns a Promise. Here is example how to define async function in interface:

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: () => Promise<void>
}
```

Instead of `void` you can use any return type you want and of course you can use any parameters you want, for example:

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: (test: string) => Promise<boolean>
}
```